# Как защитить данные при передаче cookie для сохранения доступа к аккаунту

Tags: cookie, авторизация, криптография, хеширование

Я хочу использовать cookie для автоматической авторизации пользователя после входа в аккаунт, но не знаю как это сделать безопасно. Единственное, что примдумал, это подписывать cookie закрытым ключом. В базу пользователей добавить поле для хранения случайной строки, брать hash(login + password + random string). Можно вместо random string использовать user agent, но это ненадежно. И получится что-то вроде Cookie = (user id, secret(hash)). Хотел бы знать, как это делаете вы.

Comment: Достаточно хранить в куке уникальное случайное число, а отображение из этого числа в логин на стороне сервера в базе данных. И при каждом запросе это число обновлять, чтобы супостаты, скопировавшие его из трафика, либо выгрузившие из браузера, не смогли в скриптах им пользоваться.

Comment: Зачем вообще что то хешировать? Выдавайте токен аутентификации и все дела.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Для меня это очень ценная информация :)

Comment: Сессии же тоже хранят случайную строку (php). Зачем тогда нужны сессии, если это будет то же самое по сути

Comment: Сессии php реализуются как раз куками и предназначены для того, что бы программист php мог не придумывать своих средств сохранения сессий, а пользоваться этими стандартными

Comment: @Mike но сессии хранятся недолго и, как пишут, долго они храниться не должны. А для этого вместо куки сессии рекомендуют устанавливать отдельную куку на длительное время (на год, например) и уже ее использовать, если сессия уже неактивна (создаем новую сессию тогда). Но если выдавать в куке случайную id, то это небезопасно, надо как-то защищать эти данные, а если брать случайную строку, то это и есть кука сессии, только с намного большим expires. Если значение куки меняется с каждым запросом, то тогда вообще непонятно зачем нужна кука сессии. Тогда получается без нее можно обойтись?

Comment: Почему случайная ID не безопасна ? она должна быть большой, хотя бы байт 16 в длину, дополнительно к ней можно добавить хеш вычисляемый на основе нее и некого секрета, известного только на сервере. В принципе если такая подпись есть, то ID быть случайной уже не обязательно. Я например предпочитаю прямо ID из БД использовать с подписью, что бы в БД не хранить ничего длинного и тем более случайного (особенно если вдруг используется MySQL и это первичный ключ)

Comment: @Mike спасбо. Я ошибся, имел ввиду id пользователя из базы данных небезопасно. А какие данные вы используете для подписи?

Comment: @PakUula то есть сессии в этом случае вообще не нужны? Не могу им место придумать

Comment: id пользователя там может быть, что бы не лазить лишний раз за ним в БД, но вместе с id сессии или подобной сущности, что бы можно было при необходимости эту сущность аннулировать, если вдруг решите, что поддерживать данную сессию далее нельзя (например многие известные проекты при смене пароля пользователем аннулируют все его подключения или предусматривают другие механизмы такого сброса). Подпись в общем то простая, берем то, что будет в куке, некое секретное слово, хранимое на сервере и берем от этого какой нибудь SHA-256 или больше. Результат пишем в куку вместе в данными

Comment: В куке хранится идентификатор сессии. Подробности сессии хранятся на серверной стороне.

Comment: @PakUula сессии в течении недолгого времени действуют, мне надо чтобы авторизация сохранялась. Если моя кука меняется каждый запрос, то сессия мне непонятно зачем нужна, а одной сессии мне не хватит, т.к. она быстро закончится.

Comment: @Mike спасибо, пойду эксперементировать, подумал ещё в подпись user agent добавить, может ещё чего придумаю. Про ip читал что можно старну определить, но там какие-то базы данных, все меняется, надо обновлять, не очень в общем

Comment: user agent может неожиданно поменяться при обновлении браузера и установке расширений